# adding login page for authentication to html documents

Tags: perl, apache, web-applications, cgi

I have few html documents and i want to add a login page to restrict access to those html documents. Can someone help in writing the server side script and adding required directives to apache config file.

This is what i tried:
I added a web page with login form and added a perl script in the server, which checks username and password and redirects the user to the html documents. I am not sure what directives to add in the config file for this. Without any directives, users can load the html documents directly by using direct URL of the html page. I googled for this, but mostly i could find http authentications using browser. By http authentication, i mean the authentication using AuthType. I want to have my own login page and want to redirect only authorized users to the html page. When users try to access the target html page by using the URL of that page, they should get another page with "Access Denied"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your login page in PHP or some other web scripting language, and once the password is entered, it could read in the contents of the selected page and send it out.  The trick there is to move the files outside the Document Root, so there's no way to get to them other than having your script print them out.

Your login screen could have a list of documents with a radio button on which to print (after successful login).  Or you can have one script that logs them in and sets up something in the SESSION data that other scripts can check for before printing those documents.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html). This is usually used with a Web server like Apache httpd where `.htpasswd` comes in handy. (Also, this question belongs on ServerFault.)

Comment: This is what i meant when i say http authentication, with this there is a browser default user/password dialogbox that pops up. I want to have my own login page and want to redirect only authorized users to the html page. I will update my question with this info